# Accessing direct memory addresses and obtaining the values in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-address

I was wondering if it was possible to access a direct block of memory using C/C++ and grab the value. For example:

```
int i = 15;
int *p = &i;
cout << &i;
```

If I took the printed value here, that would give me the address of the variable i, which contains the value 15. I will just say it printed out 0x0ff9c1 for this example. If I have a separate program which declares a pointer like so...

```
int *p = 0x0ff9c1;
cout << *p;
```

Would it be possible to print out that 15 that the other application placed in the memory block 0x0ff9c1? I know my pointer declaration with the memory address is incorrect, I am unsure how to do it otherwise. I have tried using `memcopy` but I have not been able to get that to work either. I know this is possible somehow as I have a program called Cheat Engine which modifies game memory address values to gain unfair advantages. I have been successful in placing the printed memory location and obtaining the value (15) though Cheat Engine. My goal is to do this using C++. 
If this is too confusing, basically I would like to access a variable that another application stored using its memory address and print out the value. I am using Windows 7 x64 with MinGW compiler if that matters. Thanks!

PS: I'll post a picture of what Cheat Engine does to give a better idea.
[image]

Comment: +1 for such experiments.

Comment: read a book about virtual memory. As an additional note: linux and some new versions of windows employ stack randomization, so the addresses of local variables will vary between the program executions.

Comment: Yes, though experimentation I discovered that. I was thinking of exporting the address though an execution argument to the second program. I will look into virtual memory, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am trying to do something similar. I was able to read a memory location from another program using a system memory reader similar to Cheat Engine. I wanted to be able to read this memory location from a program I created and I would also like to know how to predict where this is going to be in future application restarts.

Comment: There is a system call ptrace() in Linux which can do this, not sure about Windows though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two processes have separate address spaces. One process cannot access another processses memory unless it is explicily shared memory.

Comment: @Shadowalker Building on Ed's answer, the address inside the pointer is not the actual physical address inside your RAM, it is just the address local to the application (in a sense, a virtual address).

Comment: How do debuggers and other programs such as Cheat Engine access them then? From my understanding, OLLYDbg and Cheat Engine do not install kernel drivers or any serious hooks. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Which under Windows would use `ReadProcessMemory()` and `WriteProcessMemory()`.

Comment: Thanks for the downbote. Things like debuggers attach themselves to the process and therefore able to access all the memory for that process. @paul - I think somebody should read up about paging, virtual memory, segmentation and process address space.

Comment: @Shadowalker, every decent OS has debugger support to simplify these tasks (note that debuggers not just access foreign memory, they can set breakpoints and even view registers in another process's context).

Comment: @Ed Heal, Ok one final question haha. Is it possible to "attach" to a process using C++? Would I have to use x86 assembler? If I can do it in C++, any idea how to get started? Thank you!

Comment: @unkulunkulu Can't someone fool the OS that their program is a debugger and take advantage of that?

Comment: @Shadowalker, comments are not for asking additional questions, start a new one

Comment: @Paul, I don't know the exact answer, but I imagine some rights system built in OSes to control the programs being allowed to use debugging functionality.

Comment: @Paul On Windows you have to specify [access rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684880%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) when you open your process handle. On linux, I'm pretty sure you have to have root access in order to use the API.

Comment: @EdHeal: -1 for answering seconds after question was asked w/a knee-jerk response that flatly denied the OP's experience that this program exists (I don't bother with downvoting that kind of thing unless I think it's been upvoted for poor reasons).  +1 on your comment that fixes it there, but IMO it's better to fix it in your answer.  In either case, you're welcome.

Comment: @Hostile You really shouldn't downvote or upvote in response or others' opinions.

Comment: @Paul Small correction (can't edit). [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) requires that the process doing the "tracing" is the parent of the process being "traced". You can also attach yourself but that requires root access. On Windows, reading (`PROCESS_VM_READ`) another processes' memory doesn't require debugging or admin priviledge. Writting on the other hand is another matter. Oh and for what it's worth, I agree with Hostile.

Comment: @Paul: Uhhh..."One process cannot access another processses memory unless it is explicily shared memory." isn't an opinion.  It's true in a fully generalized case in terms of the language standard, but it fails to explain the existence of this program.  There must be an explanation of how this program is working or it's not a complete answer.

Comment: @Hostile You said you downvoted because "[you] think it's been upvoted for poor reasons". Undoing another person's vote is not how you should be using this feature of SO.

Comment: @Paul: Relax.  I'm just saying I didn't think it was a good answer, and although the answer is becoming spread out over a cacophony of comments on this answer, we up/down vote on the text of the answer itself.  I'll upvote it if it's refactored so the answer text gives the full story, but until then I'm rather frustrated with an answer text of "no it's impossible" being accepted.  My habits of not downvoting answers with zero are a separate concern, and it has more to do with feeling that I don't see the point of a net reputation penalty on someone who was just trying to help, even if poorly.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it in a platform-agnostic way in C++.  While I haven't used this "cheat engine" specifically, it almost certainly is using the same special API that a debugger uses.  The code will be specific to Windows, and you will require a certain privilege level on the running process.

(For instance, if you are using Visual Studio and execute a program from it in a Debug Mode, Visual Studio can look at and modify values in that program.)

I haven't written a debugger in a while, so I don't know where a good place to get started on the Debug API is, but you can search around the web for things like this article:

http://www.woodmann.com/fravia/iceman1.htm

Comment: Note: As others point out, the debugger API isn't the only privileged API that particular platforms can offer to poke around in other process.  (In fact, some embedded systems don't bother with separate address spaces at all and still let you compile C and C++ source, so your "naive" example might actually work on those very basic platforms.)  I was just guessing the odds were the Debug API was what it used--as opposed to the hooks SpyXX uses or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the memory used by another process, one way would be to inject your code into the other process. From that point, you can do whatever you want to the other program's memory as if it were your owns.

Search around for [remote thread creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [hooking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). There are more than a few questions about it here (and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx), for starters).

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not usually possible for one program to modify the memory of another. The system goes to great lengths to ensure this. If it did not, no program would be safe. This is particularly true in all the Unix variants I've worked on, though not on all proprietary OSes I've seen.

Note that none of these rules apply to the kernel ...

There is also a programming paradigm called shared memory, but you have to explicitly set that up.

Short answer: you can't usually do that. I *believe* you mentioned windows. I know nothing about Windows, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: The answer is focused a bit wrongly and strictly not exactly correct, because OS'es provide means for processes to modify each other's memory. The answer should focus on the fact that memory spaces are different, so the pointers with equal values reference different physical memory locations in different processes.

Comment: I did not feel a complete virtual memory lesson was warranted though perhaps needed.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you still could this through a DLL injection. Here is a link to a tutorial: http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/using-createremotethread-for-dll-injection-on-windows/