# Finding the address of a variable from another process

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

[visual studio screenshot with memory window open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqnVF.jpg)

Hi, I wonder if someone could kindly give me some info on something please?

Let's say that i have two programs, `program1` and `program2`.

I have this code in `program1`:

```cpp
int number = 100;
int* p = &number;  // p = 0x0050f594
```

`p` is pointing to the memory address `0x0050f594`

And in `program2` I have this:

```cpp
int* p = (int*)0x0050f594;
```

So to me, `p` from `program2`, points to the variable number from `program1`.

I think it's something to do with different applications running in their own address space, but I would still like to know how to make `program2`'s `p` pointer point to the number variable from `program1`?

Comment: You cannot, unless you are running old MS DOS. Or use some shared memory.

Comment: Ollydbg, IDA Pro, etc etc, can do this.

Comment: You can use something like `WriteProcessMemory`. I have no idea why you would want to, though, unless you were writing a debugger. This is *horrible* application design. Use a [memory-mapped file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx) if you need to share data between processes.

Comment: @CodyGray A cheat engine might be another motivation.

Comment: Well, the point is that it is not worth learning unless you are actually writing a debugger. Which is a pretty darn advanced task, probably something you shouldn't be taking on quite yet if you're asking this question. :-) For learning purposes, understanding the architectural design is more important, and there purplepsycho has your answer.

Comment: Also, I'd mention her sister: `ReadProcessMemory`.

Comment: @WhatsUp, I actually want to be able to alter the camera (or the view) of a game, to make it suitable for use with an oculus rift. I will need to hook what function controls this, but first I need to know what variables effect the camera.

Comment: Also related: [Accessing direct memory addresses and obtaining the values in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266762/accessing-direct-memory-addresses-and-obtaining-the-values-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern operating systems, processes are isolated. Each process have its own memory. The operating system is in charge of translating process memory address (when a process want to read or write into memory) into a physical address.

If you do not have operating system, or a simple (embedded platform) or if you're writting a kernel mode driver, you have a direct access to physical memory.

For x86 processor, the reading of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_mode may be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, What you need here is inter process communication, commonly refered as (IPC). That is available both in Linux or windows. So that by using any IPC mechanism you can just transfer the value to the other process and then you can do the required operation you want.

It's not the direct answer to your question but, you can always go ahead in this direction and check.

Hope This helps.

Comment: what if i have the symbole name from other process and i want to read the value that in other process